# Can't I use IEnumerable() on .ascx?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, ilist

This is my code :

```
protected IEnumerable<MyObject> CategoriesHotelsFiltrati;
CategoriesHotelsFiltrati.Union(CategoriesHotels.Where(o => o.Comune != null && CategoriesLocalitaSelezionate.Contains(o.Comune.UniqueID)));
```

now, on .asxc, if I try to do :

```
<% 
    if (m_oHotelsFiltrati == null || m_oHotelsFiltrati.Count()==0)
    {
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
%>
```

seems that it doesnt find `.Count()` method. It says somethings about "using" or "assembly". Strange, with `IList<>` this works perfectly...why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following line to your `*.ascx` file:

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

`.Count()` is an extension method, it's not actually a method of `IEnumerable`.  You need to have a `using` for `System.Linq` for the compiler to find the method. (As per comment by  Anthony Pegram, you would use the `import` command for a markup file.)

It works fine with an IList because list actually has a property `Count`; it doesn't rely on the extension method.

Answer (score 2):

With `IList<>` you're probably calling the `Count` property (without parentheses).  You can call `Count()` as a static method:

```
<%  
    if (m_oHotelsFiltrati == null || Enumerable.Count(m_oHotelsFiltrati)==0) 
    { 
        Response.Write("hello"); 
    } 
%>
```

I'm not sure how to get extension method resolution in the .ascx file.